# Can I confirm the execution of each command series in Linux?

Tags: linux

If I wish to execute the commands ls;cat test;cp test testlocation for example, can I confirm the start of each command prior to it executing? If it is possible, how do I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that each command in sequence succeeded.

In that case, do this:
`ls && cat test && cp test testlocation`

---

In response to the clarification:

Create a function called `get_confirmation`:

```
function get_confirmation() {
    echo -n "Continue? (Y/N) "
    read RESULT
    return $([ "$RESULT" = "Y" ])
}
```

Then do: `ls && get_confirmation && cat test && get_confirmation && cp test testlocation`

Comment: I mean if I execute the command ls, it first lists all the files and then asks me for confirmation if I would like to execute the next command.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Thanks for the clarification - the edit addresses this.

Comment: Thanks new123456. Wasn't aware I could simply write a function to get the confirmation. Is that the only way?

Comment: Would it be possible to email you more questions? Am a newbie at Linux and am having a hard time comprehending some of the fundamentals.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey As far as I know, `bash` has no inbuilt functionality to ask for confirmation - most every shell script will have some sort custom input function. Feel free to ask any questions here - you tend to get a very quick answer.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Also, the [Slackbook](http://www.slackbook.org/html/index.html) (though Slackware oriented) is really good for getting oriented with the command line. Chapters 8-11, 13, and 15-17 look pretty generic.